# Rails: Object saving in console but not within app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, object, sqlite3-ruby

I know this must be a dumb error somewhere, but I've been going in circles trying to figure out why my objects only save within the console, and not in the app itself.

Anyone have an idea?

Here's the code:

Controller:

```
 class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
  end

  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)

    if @job.save
      redirect_to jobs_path, flash: { notice: "You've successfully created a job." }
    else
      redirect_to new_job_path, flash: { alert: @job.errors.messages }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    if @job.update
      redirect_to jobs_path, notice: "You've updated a job."
    else
      redirect_to edit_job_path, alert: @job.errors.messages
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    if @job.destroy
      redirect_to jobs_path, notice: "You've deleted a job."
    else
      redirect_to jobs_path, alert: @job.errors.messages
    end
  end

  private

  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:poster, :category, :location, :status)
  end
end
```

And the view:

```
<h1>Create job</h1>
<form class="form">
  <%= form_for @job do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :poster, placeholder: "Poster", onclick: "placeholder = ''", onblur: "placeholder = 'Poster'", autofocus: true, class: "form-group" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :category, placeholder: "Category", onclick: "placeholder = ''", onblur: "placeholder = 'Category'", class: "form-group" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :location, placeholder: "Location", onclick: "placeholder = ''", onblur: "placeholder = 'Location'", class: "form-group" %><br>
    <%= f.select :status, ['New', 'Pending', 'Complete'],placeholder: "Status", onclick: "placeholder = ''", onblur: "placeholder = 'Status'", class: "form-group" %><br><br>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And the log:

```
Started GET "/jobs/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=FStlZTVRMKg%2Bw3Zkw5%2FdpP1w5I%2Fl4vxlQPwAGKqRjIM704p6vXWXEe9z4GmdoB4FJirP6AzUJRkCPEcEwmVNjQ%3D%3D&job%5Bposter%5D=jill&job%5Bcategory%5D=jill&job%5Blocation%5D=jill&job%5Bstatus%5D=New&commit=Submit" for ::1 at 2017-04-16 15:16:08 -0400
Processing by JobsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"FStlZTVRMKg+w3Zkw5/dpP1w5I/l4vxlQPwAGKqRjIM704p6vXWXEe9z4GmdoB4FJirP6AzUJRkCPEcEwmVNjQ==", "job"=>{"poster"=>"jill", "category"=>"jill", "location"=>"jill", "status"=>"New"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Rendered jobs/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 12.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: When you try to save in your app what errors do you get ?

Comment: @Alexander Luna Nothing - no error message. I'll add the log to the question..

Comment: This is a log of you opening the form. Where's the log of you pressing "Submit"?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev that should be it. I took the log starting from opening the page, to the page submitting redirects to. You can see where the parameters are filled out in "Parameters" (you might need to scroll sideways)

Comment: What is the name of the file of your create job form ?

Comment: Ah, I see! Remove the `<form class="form">`. Why do you have it? Also, you're missing an opening part of that `</div>`. You might want to remove it as well.

Comment: Oh haha thank you @Sergio Tulentsev you nailed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is breaking your form

```
<form class="form">
```

You can't have nested forms in HTML. So `<form>` from your `form_for` definition is not interpreted as it should.

Also, there's a dangling `</div>`.